# Firebase error: "cannot assign type User? to type User?"

Tags: ios, swift, variables, firebase

I am going to attach my code below which uses Firebase. The error which is coming across is as follows:

> FirebaseManager.swift:25:31: Cannot assign value of type `User?`
>    to type `User?`.

Here is the code:

```
class FirebaseManager: NSObject {
    static let databbaseRef = Database.database().reference()
    static var currentUserId:String = ""
    static var currentUser:User?

    static func Login(email:String, password:String, completion: @escaping (_ success:Bool) -> Void) {
        Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: { (user,error) in
            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                completion(false)
            } else {
                currentUser = user
                currentUserId = (user?.uid)!
                completion(true) }
```

Please help. The problem is in line  `currentUser = user`. Thanks.

Comment: is it cannot assign `User?` to `User` ?? `User?` to `User?` should work

Comment: no the error specifically is that cannot assign value of type 'User?' to type 'User?

Comment: honestly I am really confused

Comment: haha sorry, I see now how that was confusing... can you verify the error message again for me please?

Comment: i am sending a screenshot:

Comment: never mind do not know how but it just says that it is not possible to assign a type of User? to another type of User?

Comment: it is in the line currentUser = user the error provides no more info

Comment: that seems VERY weird to me. How can it not assign Type A to Type A??

Comment: Yeah I know that why I was struggling.

Comment: I updated the title for you to let everyone else know how WEIRD this is, hopefully you will get some more views. I upvoted but I don't know firebase :P good luck!

Comment: @DeepankarJoshi check my answer and let me know

Comment: no not really because in swift 3 FIRUser is rewritten as User thanks for trying though. This really makes no sense

Comment: @DeepankarJoshi i did not get could you explain more

Answer (score 9):

Hi i had this same problem, u have class which name is User and its in conflict with class from firebase just change

```
static var currentUser:User?
```

to

```
static var currentUser: FirebaseAuth.User?
```

Comment: Thanks! So simple, and I did not think about using it like this before :)